# Focus does not move when show panel

Tags: vb.net, user-interface

I have two textbox controls. When the first textbox gets the focus then `panel1` is made visible. `panel1` has a textbox named `textbox3`. Now when the user presses down a key in `textbox1`  the focus moves to `textbox3` inside `panel1`, when `panel1` is visible or the user moves to `textbox2`. So I tried like this

**Textbox1_Keydown**

```
If e.Keycode = Keys.Down Then

    If panel1.visible Then
        textBox3.Focus()
    Else
        textbox2.Focus()
    End if

End if
```

**Textbox2_Keydown**

```
If e.Keycode = Keys.Down Then

    textbox3.Focus()

End If
```

And I wrote a leave event for `textbox1`. When focus moves from `textbox1` to another control (not inside the panel or inside the textbox) the panels `Visible` property is set to `false`

**textbox1_Leave, textbox3_Leave**

```
If Not (Me.ActiveControl Is textbox3 Or _
        Me.ActiveControl Is textbox2 Or _
        Me.ActiveControl Is Nothing) Then

    pnlSalesOrder.Visible = False
End If
```

But when I press down a key in `textbox1`  `panel1.Visible` is changed  to `false` and the focus moves to `textbox2` why?
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have any KeyDown code for TextBox2?

Comment: yes. i have. its move to another control in form @Mych

Comment: Can you show that code... Could you also place a breakpoint in your code and the test and step through the code to see where the code is moving focus.

Comment: that code invoke when press down key in textbox2. @Mych

Comment: If you can show the code for textbox2 it would help... you do realise that textbox1 and textbox2 will never get any text entered because as soon as you press a key the focus will go into another control.

Comment: @Mych Check My Question

Comment: Not sure I understand the issue. `when I press down a key in textbox2, panel1.Visible is set to false and the focus moves to textbox2`.  How does the focus *move* to textbox2 if the user is already in textbox2?  Try posting the code that will duplicate the issue for your audience.

Comment: @LarsTech Check Question sir